# I want to make a Desktop App with Flask and flask web gui

Tags: flask

I want to create Desktop App with Flask and flaskwebgui, for example like this way: https://medium.com/@fareedkhandev/create-desktop-application-using-flask-framework-ee4386a583e9

but when trying the same for my application it throws the following error:

> TypeError: Flask.**call**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'environ' and 'start_response'

And i ask myself why that is the case

```
chrome_path = "chrome\\chrome.exe"
app = Flask(__name__)
last_update_time = None 
ui = FlaskUI(app, width = 800 , height = 800, browser_path= chrome_path)
engine = create_engine(db.DATABASE_PATH)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    message = request.args.get('message')
    lastStatus = getLastStatus.getLastStatusTimeDiffHtml()
    getWorstStatus = getLastStatus.get_worst_status()
    return render_template('index.html', lastStatus = lastStatus,last_update_time=last_update_time, getWorstStatus=getWorstStatus)


def update_database():
    global last_update_time
    now = datetime.now()
    last_update_time = now
    getData.updateDatabase()
    parseData.parsedData(update=True)
    
    

@app.route('/update_database', methods=['POST']) #/update_database
def update_database_route():
    update_thread = Thread(target=update_database)
    update_thread.start()
    time.sleep(3)
    return redirect(url_for('index', popup='Database refreshed'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.run(debug=True)
    ui.run ()
```

Now i just commented ui.run() out and made the FlaskUI in the main, and now it works but now im just even more confused

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.run(debug=True)
    #ui.run ()
    FlaskUI(app=app, server="flask").run()
```